# Parsing XML and storing data into NSMuttableArray

Tags: objective-c, xml, xcode, arrays, nsmutablearray

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing XML data to NSMutableArray iOS - iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884702/parsing-xml-data-to-nsmutablearray-ios-iphone)

```
<ForecastResult>
<Forecast>
<Date>2012-06-27T00:00:00</Date>
<WeatherID>4</WeatherID>
<Desciption>Sunny</Desciption>
<Temperatures>
<MorningLow/>
<DaytimeHigh>100</DaytimeHigh>
</Temperatures>
<ProbabilityOfPrecipiation>
<Nighttime/>
<Daytime>00</Daytime>
</ProbabilityOfPrecipiation>
</Forecast>
<Forecast>
<Date>2012-06-28T00:00:00</Date>
<WeatherID>4</WeatherID>
<Desciption>Sunny</Desciption>
<Temperatures>
<MorningLow>74</MorningLow>
<DaytimeHigh>95</DaytimeHigh>
</Temperatures>
<ProbabilityOfPrecipiation>
<Nighttime>10</Nighttime>
<Daytime>00</Daytime>
</ProbabilityOfPrecipiation>
</Forecast>
```

The above is my XML file and i want to read Date and DaytimeHigh into  NSMuttableArray. I am using NSXML parser .

Comment: I saw that question but could not understand. the element names are not clear categlist is not found in that XML file can u clarify which categlist is what in that post

Comment: In that post, `categList` is an NSMutableArray. The OP in that question wants to parse XML data into `categList`.

Comment: what does categList "if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"categList"])"

Comment: Is a Muttable array one that you can put dogs into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were asking about `categList` in the question I said was a duplicate. You shouldn't focus on the question, but rather the answer. The answer in that question suggests that you use [XMLReader](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/09/simple-xml-to-nsdictionary-converter/), which allows for easy XML parsing into NSDictionary objects. Then you could pass the dictionary objects into an NSArray. For detailed instructions on how to use XMLReader, go to the linked page above. Here's how you would pass the NSDictionary values n an NSMutableArray:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayFromDictionary = [dictionaryWithXMLData allValues];
```

Hope this helps!