# Parse XML file from web site into UITextView

Tags: ios, xml, xcode

I'm working on a Bible quote of day application for iOS and was wondering how I could parse `XML` data hosted online to be displayed in a `UITextView` in my application.

```
<bible>
<title>John 1:14</title>
<item>
<bookname>John</bookname>
<chapter>1</chapter>
<verse>14</verse>
<text>
Now the Word became flesh and took up residence among us. We saw his glory – the glory of the one and only, full of grace and truth, who came from the Father.
</text>
</item>
<results>1</results>
</bible>
```

I'm thinking of parsing `<title>` in one `UITextView` and `<text>` in another `UITextView`. Can anyone help with this? Is using Apple's `NSXMLParser` a viable option?

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9884929/1153630

Answer (score 1):

if number of results is always **1**, then you can just split the string to get required fields.

For example, for your xml string,

Code

```
NSString *data = @"<bible><title>John 1:14</title><item><bookname>John</bookname><chapter>1</chapter>    <verse>14</verse>    <text>    Now the Word became flesh and took up residence among us. We saw his glory – the glory of the one and only, full of grace and truth, who came from the Father.    </text>    </item>    <results>1</results>    </bible>";
NSString *title = [data componentsSeparatedByString:@"<title>"][1];
title=[title componentsSeparatedByString:@"</title>"][0];
NSLog(@"%@",title);

NSString *text = [data componentsSeparatedByString:@"<text>"][1];
text=[text componentsSeparatedByString:@"</text>"][0];
NSLog(@"%@",text);

// now assign them to textViews
titleTextView.text=title;
textTextView.text=text;
```

Comment: More looking on how to parse the two specified elements from an XML file into a UITextView, and what to do..

Answer (score 1):

I use to parse a xml usually this lib

https://github.com/nicklockwood/XMLDictionary

It is quite easy to parse a xml and use the data to fill your tableView

NSDictionary * baseDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithXMLData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath]];